# Groovy - database connection - simple CRUD operations

Tags: sql, oracle, session, groovy, connection

Let's assume I work with database in a following way.

I create *new sql instance*:

```
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(connString)
```

then I do some operations over DB:

```
def datum
try {
    String query = "select * from (select max(extractdate) as ex from confirmed_jobs where inputsystem = '${inputsystem}') " +
                   "where ex NOT IN (SELECT extdate FROM bundling_launch b WHERE b.launchtype = 'automatic' and b.inputsystem = '${inputsystem}')"
    def result = sql.firstRow(query)
    datum = sql.firstRow(query)[0]
} catch (Exception ex) {
    println ex
    throw ex
}
```

.. and always *close* the connection.

```
sql.close()
```

To sum this up - create new sql instance, do some operation and close it.

Can I use this simple approach in not data-heavy application? Are there some risks - instantiating an object for each DB operation?

Comment: This also came to my mind. In general, I would like to avoid singleton pattern, if possible.

Comment: As you can use the drivers manager facility for your newInstance(), I would recommend using DataSource, then it supports distributed transactions. One more thing: if you're using new Sql(connection) beware that in this case, Groovy SQL
cannot manage that connection and you have to take care of properly closing it yourself.
Finally, if you have a Sql instance and you need a second one with the same characteristics
(a clone), you can use new Sql(db).